# how to submit specifically website to Google.fr, Google.de

Tags: magento, seo, search-engine

situation is :
one website (based on Magento ecommerce solution), different storeviews, all accessible through the same domain but an extension is then redirecting to the correct storeview based on customer location.

I have one storeview for Germany, one for USA, and a fallback worldwide, the first is in EUR and tax included, the second and third are in USD and tax excluded.

I submit my product price with the structured data scheme (itemprop).

I have one sitemap for each storeview and submit them all to Google.

The problem : In Germany, when I google my product, I got my URL from my worldwide storeview (which is not the killer as my extension will redirect afterwards) but with the USD price.

How to do so that I submit my sitemap from the germany storeview to Google.de and not my worldwide storeview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use ccTLD

The best way to target different countries is to use [ccTLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain).
This is what they're made for and Google use it to determine the targeted location of your website.

### Configure Google Webmaster Tools

In the Google webmaster tools, you can set your geographic target to a website.

As said on [Google Help Center](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399):

> #### Set a geographic target:
>
> 1. On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want.
> 2. Click the gear icon (top right corner), and then click Site Settings.
> 3. In the Geographic target section, select the option you want.
>
> If you want to ensure that your site is not associated with any country or region, select Unlisted in the drop-down list.

### Use Link rel alternate hreflang

You can use the declaration of different language version to target countries in the `<head>`of your pages.
This use the `<link>` tag like this :

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr" hreflang="fr-FR" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de" hreflang="de-DE" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/us" hreflang="en-US” />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

You need to declare every version of each URL on every pages. Exemple above needs to be on every URL of the example.

Read further on [Google Help Center about telling Google your different localized target](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077).

Comment: thanks for the answer, the ccTLD are simply not an option because those we would need are already used by someone else (yes our Company name is kind of generic). I can find where in webmasters tools, can you help a bit further?

Comment: I added the infos in the answer

Comment: thanks a lot, I actually could do nothing as my TLD is localized (it is a ccTLD) and is not on my target country. :(. Anyway, thanks for the detailed answer that will help me for other websites :).